# How to create this element on OS X?

Tags: macos

I find that I can't find this element on the XIB. How can I create this thing on OS X? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: this is not an UI element available in IB. You'll need to build it yourself based on a NSView or fake it using a gradient button. The latter won't work so well, though.

Comment: It's not clear, but the arrow may be pointing to the [bottom bar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-SW6). I'm still on an old version of IB, but it was the Content Border section of the Size inspector for the window.

Answer (score 2):

That's a [bottom bar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-SW6) with a label (text field) control in it. In IB, select the window, then select the Size inspector (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd>). There, you will find a Content Border pop-up menu. Select either Small or Large Bottom Border. Then, drag a label control into the border area. Then use the normal techniques to set the content of the label. For static content, you can just edit it in IB. Otherwise, you can use bindings to do it or set up an outlet and set it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [NSPathControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSPathControl_class/Reference/Reference.html), which ***does*** exist in Interface Builder:

[image: NSPathControl]

And here's [an Apple sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ObjectPath/Introduction/Intro.html) that might help you out.

Comment: I mean, the `13 items, 144.2 GB available` not the file path.